# How to pass values of selected checkboxes from multiple pages in from a table in thymeleaf and pass them to the controller

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I have a table which span on multiple pages. I have a checkbox on each row of the table.
The poblem is that when only Ids of the row I select in the current page I am at are passed to my controller.

Below is my javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        var checkboxes = $("input[type='checkbox']");
        var ids = [];
        checkboxes.on('click', function(event) {
        if($(this).prop('checked')){
            ids.push(this.value);
            console.log(this.value);
        } else {

        }
        });

        $('#Button').click(function () {
            var form = $("#Form");
            var url = form.attr("action");
            $.post(url, {ids: ids}, function (data) {
                $("#msg").html(data);
                console.log("...");
                console.log(ids);
            });
        })

    </script>
```

Below is my table

```
<div class="table-responsive table-striped" id="ajax">
                        <form th:action="@{/SubmitAJAX}" th:object="${project}" id="Form"
                              method="POST">
                            <table id="example"
                                   class="table table-hover table-striped tm-table-striped-even mt-3">
                                <thead>
                                <tr class="tm-bg-gray">
                                    <th scope="col" class="text-center">Applicant Name</th>
                                    <th scope="col" class="text-center">Applicant Id No</th>
                                    <th scope="col">To be sent</th>
                                </tr>
                                </thead>
                                <tbody>

                                <th:block th:if="${units!=null && project!=null}">
                                    <th:block th:each="p : ${units}">
                                        <tr>
                                            <td class="text-center" th:text="${p.applicantFullName}+ ' ' + ${p.applicantSurname}"></td>
                                            <td class="text-center" th:text="${p.applicantIdNumber}"></td>
                                            <td class="text-center" >
                                            <td style="text-align:center; vertical-align:middle;">

                                                <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox" th:if="${hasInspectionRequestBeCreatedToday==false and p.constructionStatus!='UNIT COMPLETED'}">
                                                    <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input tab1_chk" th:id="${p.unitId}" name="units" th:value="${p.unitId}">
                                                    <label class="custom-control-label" th:for="${p.unitId}"></label>
                                                </div>
                                                
                                                <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox" th:unless="${hasToday==false and p.constructionStatus!='COMPLETED'}">
                                                    <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input tab1_chk" th:id="${p.unitId}" name="units" th:value="${p.unitId}" disabled>
                                                    <label class="custom-control-label" th:for="${p.unitId}"></label>
                                                </div>                                                  
                                            </td>

                                        </tr>
                                    </th:block>
                                </th:block>
                                </tbody>
                            </table>
                            <div style="text-align:center">
                                <input type="button" id="Button" disabled class="btn btn-primary tab1_btn" value="Submit Button" />
                            </div>
                            
                        </form>

                    </div>
```

This is my controller

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = "/submitAJAX")
public String submitRequest(Model model, 
                                      @RequestParam(value="ids") int [] ids,
                                              HttpServletRequest request) {

                  .........
```

Answer (score 0):

***Current Problem*** :

Your current jquery code pushes the checked checkboxes in array but , there is no code for checking if the checkbox which was previously added inside array is checked/unchecked while sending that to controller.

***Solution*** :

Instead of pushing id value in array on click of the checkbox you can verify the checked checkboxes while submitting the form via ajax. i.e :

```
 var ids = $('input[type=checkbox][name=units]:checked').map(function() {
        return this.value;
  }).get();
```

Then, passed above array to your ajax call using *JSON.stringify* or whatever way you prefer.

***Demo Code*** :

```js
$('#Button').click(function() {
  var form = $("#Form");
  var url = form.attr("action");
  var ids = $('input[type=checkbox][name=units]:checked').map(function() {
    return this.value;
  }).get();

  console.log(JSON.stringify(ids))
  //your ajax call ...
})
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.6.3/dist/jquery.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<form th:action="@{/SubmitAJAX}" th:object="${project}" id="Form" method="POST">
  <table id="example" class="table table-hover table-striped tm-table-striped-even mt-3">
    <thead>
      <tr class="tm-bg-gray">
        <th scope="col" class="text-center">Applicant Name</th>
        <th scope="col" class="text-center">Applicant Id No</th>
        <th scope="col">To be sent</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td class="text-center">XYZ</td>
        <td class="text-center" th:text="${p.applicantIdNumber}">123</td>
        <td class="text-center">
          <td style="text-align:center; vertical-align:middle;">

            <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
              <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input tab1_chk" id="1" name="units" value="1">
              <label class="custom-control-label" for="1"></label>
            </div>
          </td>

      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="text-center">Something..</td>
        <td class="text-center" th:text="${p.applicantIdNumber}">123</td>
        <td class="text-center">
          <td style="text-align:center; vertical-align:middle;">

            <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
              <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input tab1_chk" id="2" name="units" value="2">
              <label class="custom-control-label" for="2"></label>
            </div>
          </td>

      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="text-center">Something 3</td>
        <td class="text-center" th:text="${p.applicantIdNumber}">12</td>
        <td class="text-center">
          <td style="text-align:center; vertical-align:middle;">

            <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
              <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input tab1_chk" id="3" name="units" value="3">
              <label class="custom-control-label" for="3"></label>
            </div>
          </td>

      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <div style="text-align:center">
    <input type="button" id="Button" class="btn btn-primary tab1_btn" value="Submit Button" />
  </div>

</form>
```

Comment: Thank you @Swati . However, It only works for few items. But when you have items that span on multiples pages, it only takes the ids that are current page from which you press the button unfortunately.

Comment: Can you share your entire html structure ? Also, for the input-box which is shown in your asked question i.e : `[name=units]`  i have added this in selector . You can remove that and try it will get all the checkboxes in your page . i.e : `$('input[type=checkbox]:checked').map..`